# React Native : Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `coordinate` of type `number` supplied to `MapMarker`, expected `object`

Tags: react-native, axios, react-native-maps

I'm building my first app, a city guide app.

I'm still very new to React Native and I'm having a problem with `react-native-maps` (I think).

I'm trying to get the markers that show up on the map to come from my database via Axios queries

This is my Axios :

```
import axios from 'axios';

// URL API BASE
const APIURL = 'http://10.22.101.55:5000/api';


// RECUPERATION DES RESTAURANTS
export const getAllRestaurant = (nom, adresse, ville, cp, telephone, email, latitude, longitude ) => axios.get(`${APIURL}/restaurant`, {
    nom: nom,
    adresse: adresse,
    ville: ville,
    cp: cp,
    telephone: telephone,
    email: email,
    latitude: latitude,
    longitude: longitude
});
```

I had to change the URL of my call otherwise I received a Network Error type error
(Localhost -> 10.22.101.55)

My page where I call Axios :

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';

// Récupération des données
import {getAllRestaurant} from '../service/emplacements'

export default function AccueilScreen() {

  // RECUPERATION DES RESTAURANTS
  const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = React.useState([])
  const LesRestaurants = () => [
    getAllRestaurant().then(response => {
      setRestaurants(response.data);
      console.log(response);
    }).catch(err => console.log('API :' + err))
  ]

  // CHARGEMENT DES RESTAURANTS
  useEffect(() => {
    LesRestaurants()
  },[])


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     <MapView
      scrollEnabled={false}
      rotateEnabled={false}
      zoomEnabled={false}
      minZoomLevel={0}
      maxZoomLevel={13}
      style={styles.map}
      region={{
         latitude: 49.4826616,
         longitude: 1.7245633,
         latitudeDelta: 0.015,
         longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
      }}
     >
      {restaurants.map((restaurant) => (
        <Marker
          key={restaurant.id}
          coordinate={restaurant.latitude, restaurant.longitude}
          title={restaurant.nom}
        />
      ))}
    </MapView>
   </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
 });
```

And this what I got in the console  :

```
Object {
  "config": Object {
    "adapter": [Function xhrAdapter],
    "data": undefined,
    "headers": Object {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    },
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "method": "get",
    "timeout": 0,
    "transformRequest": Array [
      [Function transformRequest],
    ],
    "transformResponse": Array [
      [Function transformResponse],
    ],
    "url": "http://10.22.101.55:5000/api/restaurant",
    "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus],
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
  },
  "data": Array [
    Object {
      "adresse": "17 Rue de la France",
      "cp": 76220,
      "createdAt": "2021-05-10T07:41:25.000Z",
      "email": "lerestaurant@gmail.com",
      "id": 1,
      "latitude": 49.4813,
      "longitude": 1.73745,
      "nom": "Le Restaurant",
      "telephone": "0685459547",
      "updatedAt": "2021-05-10T07:41:25.000Z",
      "ville": "Gournay",
    },
  ],
  "headers": Object {
    "cache-control": "public, max-age=0",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "content-length": "268",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",        
    "date": "Mon, 10 May 2021 08:14:35 GMT",
    "etag": "W/\"10c-flj/WYuf2hJDQ4N+xG++sHgKueQ\"",
    "keep-alive": "timeout=5",
    "x-powered-by": "Express",
  },
  "request": XMLHttpRequest {
    "DONE": 4,
    "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2,
    "LOADING": 3,
    "OPENED": 1,
    "UNSENT": 0,
    "_aborted": false,
    "_cachedResponse": undefined,
    "_hasError": false,
    "_headers": Object {
      "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    },
    "_incrementalEvents": false,
    "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": Object {
      "cache-control": "public, max-age=0",
      "connection": "keep-alive",
      "content-length": "268",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "date": "Mon, 10 May 2021 08:14:35 GMT",
      "etag": "W/\"10c-flj/WYuf2hJDQ4N+xG++sHgKueQ\"",        
      "keep-alive": "timeout=5",
      "x-powered-by": "Express",
    },
    "_method": "GET",
    "_perfKey": "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://10.22.101.55:5000/api/restaurant",
    "_requestId": null,
    "_response": "[{\"id\":1,\"nom\":\"Le Restaurant\",\"adresse\":\"17 Rue de la France\",\"ville\":\"Gournay\",\"cp\":76220,\"telephone\":\"0685459547\",\"email\":\"lerestaurant@gmail.com\",\"latitude\":49.4813,\"longitude\":1.73745,\"createdAt\":\"2021-05-10T07:41:25.000Z\",\"updatedAt\":\"2021-05-10T07:41:25.000Z\"}]",
    "_responseType": "",
    "_sent": true,
    "_subscriptions": Array [],
    "_timedOut": false,
    "_trackingName": "unknown",
    "_url": "http://10.22.101.55:5000/api/restaurant",        
    "readyState": 4,
    "responseHeaders": Object {
      "Cache-Control": "public, max-age=0",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Content-Length": "268",
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",      
      "Date": "Mon, 10 May 2021 08:14:35 GMT",
      "ETag": "W/\"10c-flj/WYuf2hJDQ4N+xG++sHgKueQ\"",        
      "Keep-Alive": "timeout=5",
      "X-Powered-By": "Express",
    },
    "responseURL": "http://10.22.101.55:5000/api/restaurant", 
    "status": 200,
    "timeout": 0,
    "upload": XMLHttpRequestEventTarget {},
    "withCredentials": true,
  },
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": undefined,
}
```

And the error message in the console + the error display

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `coordinate` of type `number`
> supplied to `MapMarker`, expected `object`.
> [image]

For me, the error is made because of the coordinate that I give to `<Marker/>`

Thanks in advance for your help and your time !

EDIT : The error is truly coming from coordinate, when I give manually the latitude and longitude, everything is working just fine.

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't know that you can accept your own anwser. I've made a Anwser but I can accept it in 2 days. Gotta wait I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change :

```
coordinate={restaurant.latitude, restaurant.longitude}
```

to

```
coordinate={{latitude: restaurant.latitude, longitude: restaurant.longitude}}
```

the error was due to my syntax which was bad.
I was not giving latitude and longitude correctly to the coordinate prop.
And Coordinate cannot be 'null' or 'undefine'.

Comment: If you explain why that code helps you can have an upvote right away. ;-)

Comment: Well ... I don't really know how to explain it but, my first syntax was wrong and it didn't give the latitude and the longitude of the restaurant to the coordinate prop. And coordinate can't be null or undefine.

Comment: Then just [edit] and explain that it was a simple syntax error. If that is what it was then it is a good explanation (I know so little about this that it totally convinces me....).